# Past Simple or Present Perfect to express an antecedent event

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect, simple-past

> We **_** Harold for three years before he died.

a) knew. b) have known.

Which answer should I use in my exam question? I have doubts, as I want to choose **a**, but a friend of mine advises me to choose **b**.

Comment: Simple Past can work, but Past Perfect is better still. Depends on context and register.

Comment: Both of them are incorrect; past perfect (_had known_) is what you want. If you're sure you transcribed the exam right, don't take any more exams made up by the same person.

Comment: @JohnLawler You could also use the past simple, couldn't you? I agree that it is not as good, but it does seem to me to work. *We knew Harold for three years before he died*.

Comment: It's OK if you want to focus on knowing him for three years as a continuous activity, which is a little odd for a stative verb like _know_. But the present perfect is right out.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes. I always tend to think of *know* in a continuing sense. Sometimes people will say 'I don't feel I know him like I used to', suggesting that 'knowing' needs nurturing in order to continue. But you will agree, I've no doubt, that it would be alright to say: *We admired Harold for three years before he died*

Comment: I'd use 'when'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dr. Lawler pointed out in comments, *had known* (past perfect) is the correct tense for a continuous activity that started and ended in the past. The simple past (*knew*) is fine as well, but it is used more often for a discrete event.

See this representation from a previous Question ([How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/)):

[image]

*Have known* carries into the present.

Answer (score 0):

Since he is no longer among us (alive) I would rather choosing "past simple" than "present perfect" because there is no more connection between the past and the present.